# AngularJS ng-click only working on second click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-show

Attempting to collapse a dropdown menu (language selection), within a mobile bootstrap navbar. On first click, the dropdown menu with the languages opens fine, after changing languages the dropdown language menu closes, but when I attempt to change the language again, I have to double click the dropdown for it to open. Can anyone help me with this?

```
    <li class="dropdown" dropdown style="margin-top: 25%; left: 7.5%;">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle role="button" ng-click="visible = true">
                {{vm.languageSel.name}}
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a >
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-show="visible">
                <li ng-repeat="lang in vm.languages" ng-click="$parent.visible = false">
                    <a ng-click="vm.chgLang($index)">
                        {{lang.name}}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: maybe it's a propagation problem, have you tried to have the 2 click events in the same place? `<a ng-click="vm.chgLang($index); $parent.visible = false">` (and removing it from the `li`)

Comment: went ahead and tried that, still the same issue.

Comment: went ahead and edited post with more details

Comment: something else must interfer with your code, i gave a quick try of your code (in a ionic 1 test project, was easiest with my current setup, uses Angular v1.5.3), without modification and it worked fine.

Comment: Before posting more code, you should inspect your app in a browser's developper tools and check the event listeners bound to your element and its parents. As i couldn't reproduce your issue, something else must interfer, but we can't look to the whole code for that, it might even not be in it and caused by a plugin you didn't write, the running app is needed to isolate the guilty one here.

Comment: Went ahead and did that, I think its an issue with ng-show and ng-show interfering with bootstraps dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `visible` is initialised by default to false. Try to add `ng-init="visible = true"` on the first `li` directive

Comment: Still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the $parent. Can you try without it? Like this:

```
<li class="dropdown" dropdown style="margin-top: 25%; left: 7.5%;">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle role="button" ng-click="visible = true">
            {{vm.languageSel.name}}
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a >
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-show="visible">
            <li ng-repeat="lang in vm.languages" ng-click="visible = false">
                <a ng-click="vm.chgLang($index)">
                    {{lang.name}}
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: still no luck, would it be helpful to post more of my code?